# Can I student visa holder in France exit Schengen from another country?

Tags: france, barcelona

As a student in France with a long-term student visa, I want to go from Barcelona airport back to my country. Is it possible or do I have to exit from France only?

Comment: You can travel through and out of all Schengen countries as long as your main stay is in the country you study.

Comment: In a word, yes.